# jQuery $.ajax response empty, but only in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

I've exhausted every avenue of research to solve this one so hopefully someone else will think of something I just didn't.

Relatively straight forward setup, I have a html page with some javascript that makes an ajax request to a URL (in the same domain) the java web app in the background does its stuff and returns a partial html page (no html, head or body tags, just the content) which should be inserted at a particular point in the page.

All sounds pretty easy and the code I have works in IE, Firefox and Safari, but not in Chrome. In Chrome the target element just ends up empty and if I look at the resource request in Chromes developer tools the response content is also empty.

All very confusing, I've tried a myriad of things to solve it and I'm just out of ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var container = $('#container');

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/path/to/local/url',
    data: data('parameters=value&another=value2'),
    dataType: 'html',
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: requestBefore,
    complete: requestComplete,
    success: requestSuccess,
    error: requestError
});

function data(parameters) {
    var dictionary = {};
    var pairs = parameters.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        var keyValuePair = pairs[i].split('=');
        dictionary[keyValuePair[0]] = keyValuePair[1];
    }
    return dictionary;
}

function requestBefore() {
    container.find('.message.error').hide();
    container.prepend('<div class="modal"><div class="indicator">Loading...</div></div>');
}

function requestComplete() {
    container.find('.modal').remove();
}

function requestSuccess(response) {
    container.empty();
    container.html(response);
}

function requestError(response) {
    if (response.status == 200 && response.responseText == 'OK') {
        requestSuccess(response);
    } else {
        container.find('.message.error').fadeIn('slow');
    }
}
```

All of this is executed in a $(document).ready(function() {});

Cheers,
Jim

@Oleg - Additional information requested, an example of the response that the ajax call might receive.

```
<p class="message error hidden">An unknown error occured while trying to
retrieve data, please try again shortly.</p>
<div class="timeline">
   <a class="icon shuttle-previous"
rel="max_id=16470650733&page=1&q=something">Newer Data</a>
   <a class="icon shuttle-next"
rel="max_id=16470650733&page=3&q=something">Older Data</a>
</div>
<ol class="social">
   <li class="even">
       <div class="avatar">
           <img src="sphere_normal.gif"/>
       </div>
       <p>
           Some Content<br/>
           <span class="published">Jun 18, 2010 11:29:05 AM</span> - <a
target="_blank" href="">Direct Link</a>
       </p>
   </li>
   <li class="odd">
       <div class="avatar">
           <img src="sphere_normal.gif"/>
       </div>
       <p>
           Some Content<br/>
           <span class="published">Jun 18, 2010 11:29:05 AM</span> - <a
target="_blank" href="">Direct Link</a>
       </p>
   </li>
</ol>
<div class="timeline">
   <a class="icon shuttle-previous"
rel="max_id=16470650733&page=1&q=something">Newer Data</a>
   <a class="icon shuttle-next"
rel="max_id=16470650733&page=3&q=something">Older Data</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you running this locally?

Comment: Yes Nick all of this is running under a Java web app and so is on my local machine at the moment as http://localhost:8090/

Comment: @roguepixel - For a quick test, try running chrome with a `--disable-web-security` option on the command line, same result?

Comment: @Nick, yes sadly the same result, I spotted that one on a similar question a while ago.

Comment: @roguepixel - Interesting, the empty response seems like it's blocked cross-domain, but that should fix it...as a test not a solution of course (did you have *all* chrome windows closed when you tried it?)

Comment: @Nick, I've just closed all my chrome windows and started up again with the option you suggested and still an empty element. Just tested in the other browsers just to be sure and everything is still working as expected in the rest.

Comment: @roguepixel - Very odd, not sure I can give any more advice unless there's a URL we could hit somewhere, something's definitely a bit off, but nothing from this code that I can see.

Comment: @Nick, unfortunately there's no URL as it's for a private company web application, thanks for your thoughts though.

Comment: Could you post the contain of HTML which will be send back from `/path/to/local/url?parameters=value&another=value2`. Probably the problem can be solved only having this additional information.

Comment: Test your data function. And check that the MIME returned from the XHR is HTML.

Comment: @user257493 - Yep I've checked the data function, seems to be alright. The response header `Content-Type` is the same in all browsers `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`

Comment: @Oleg - Please see my additional information added to the original question where I can format it better.

Comment: you should try to sniff the traffic with a tcp/ip tool, for e.g. **tcpdump** or **wireshark**

Comment: @roguepixel you should try with Content-Type = text/plain

Comment: what is the status response header coming back from the server, 200? 
did you use a tool like Fiddler to examine all of the headers going to your server and back? 
are they all identical in Chrome vs working browser? if, you can see in fiddler, that the server returns blank body, there MUST be a difference in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome stepped onto its own foot with local files security, so no AJAXing local files with relative paths:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=47416

Answer (score 3):

I just resolved a similar problem, and thought I'd post my solution in case it's of use for anyone else.

Only Firefox and Chrome were showing an empty ajax response, so it seemed to be a cross domain problem, yet everything was on the same domain.

It turned out that the 'www.', which I had superfluously and stupidly hard-coded into my ajax url was to blame.  Had I been using a relative path, everything would've been fine.

I had my test site open at that particular moment as "http://domain.com", with no 'www.', so Firefox and Chrome treated it as a different domain.  Navigating to "http://www.domain.com" resulted in the ajax call working in all browers.

So, given that you wrote:

url: '/path/to/local/url'

..as is the convention when we don't want to disclose our paths, I couldn't help but wonder if in fact you had written an absolute path, just as I had...?

Comment: You saved my day! I just tried AJAX call in Chrome 8.0.552.237 <br>
 - with a relative path "bin/test.php" (the server is in my local network) -> it is working fine <br>
 - with an absolute path "http://192.168.0.101/bin/test.php" (the server is in my local network) -> it is NOT working!!!<br>
<br>
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I took your source code and set up a quick test scenario but fail to replicate your problem. It is working for me just fine in both Firefox (3.6.3) and Chrome (5.0.375.70). I tried it both locally and on a remote server.

So your code is most likely not to blame. But I would also think that it's not generally a Chrome related issue.

[Other people](http://www.plee.me/blog/2009/08/ajax-with-chrome-empty-responsetext/) seem to have come across this though. Changing the content type had no effect in my test scenario though. It even works when I set the `Content-Type` to `image/jpeg`.

On the [JQuery forums](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/load-and-ajax-not-working-on-google-chrome) someone indicated differing behavior depending on whether he runs his application locally or on a remote server. If this was the case for you, you could compare HTTP request and response headers to track down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, I'll have a bit more of a look into the request and response headers.