# Ajax request succeeds but result is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am building a Google Chrome browser extension that uses `$.ajax` requests to send data from webpages to my server (currently hosted using localhost). The `content_script.js` file that is being executed in the context of the webpages ([more on content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)) that the extension has access to runs this code:

```
//note: encode64String is assigned earlier in the script...

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost:8888/quartzsite/uploadendpoint.php",
type: "jsonp",
data: {img: encode64String},
contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
success: function(data){
    console.log("The ajax request succeeded!");
    console.log("The result is: ");
    console.log(data);
},
error: function(){
    console.log("The request failed");
}
});
```

The problem is that the `Ajax` request is succeeding but the `data` argument that it returns is empty...

The console looks like this after the code is run:[image]

Currently the contents of the `uploadedendpoint.php` file are:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  echo 'This comes from php file'; die();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

This means there should be at least something being returned in the `data` variable.

I have further confirmed that the request is succeeding because when I send the request to a broken url (i.e. uploaddddddendpoint.php) the code inside the `$.ajax`'s `error` parameter is executed.

I have read similar questions like [jQuery $.ajax response empty, but only in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068808/jquery-ajax-response-empty-but-only-in-chrome) but to no avail...

**UPDATE**:

I have removed the invalid second `type: "jsonp"` parameter entirely and have added `dataType: "text/html"`. I am now getting a failed `ajax` request each time the code is run.

**UPDATE**: Strangely changing `dataType : "text/html"` to `dataType : "html"` causes the `ajax` request to succeed but again with a blank `data` variable.
**UPDATE**: When using the dev toolkit to monitor the Network XHR these are the sent/response messages:

[image]
[image]

With regards to the flag of possible duplication to 
[Impossible to cross site ajax api calls in a chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515031/impossible-to-cross-site-ajax-api-calls-in-a-chrome-extension) I suggest otherwise! I have investigated that question and the problem does NOT seem to be the same.

Comment: Try this on your first line of the php file: `<?php echo 'This comes from php file'; die(); ?>` - Check if you get this in the console.

Comment: what does the Network tab show? try removing `jsonp` type.

Comment: go to the network pane of your chrome dev tools and see what the script returns

Comment: @akonsu I removed `type : "jsonp"` but no change. Originally I didn't specify a type but that didn't work so I thought that I would try `jsonp`. I will leave it typeless for now. The network tab shows only one failed `GET` request sent from `adzerk1_2_4_43,adzerk2_2_17_45?keywords=javascript,jquery...` but that seems to be from this page (I am testing it on stack right now).

Comment: The network pane will only display data from the page you're no, not all windows. Open the dev tools on your test page.

Comment: are you doing cross domain request?

Comment: @akonsu I am not but according to [this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html) they should be allowed anyway. I also added `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` to my code to allow them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Impossible to cross site ajax api calls in a chrome extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515031/impossible-to-cross-site-ajax-api-calls-in-a-chrome-extension)

Comment: @RobW I have my `permissions` in the manifest set to `http://*/*`. Is this incorrect? My `content_security_policy` is `"script-src 'self' http://localhost; object-src 'self' http://localhost"` Note I am not using `jsonp`.

Comment: @RobW I do not find that to be the same question.

Comment: @Prisoner I have updated the question with images from the dev tools!

Comment: @Brannon, click response to see what your page returned. To be honest though, it seems like your call isn't the issue but something else.

Comment: @Prisoner the response is empty =/

Comment: @Brannon, and that's your problem. Somethings not getting through.

Comment: @Prisoner seems as much... Does that mean that data sent in `post` woun't get to the page? Any idea what would be causing this?

Comment: @Brannon http cannot be whitelisted. Only https. Have you also checked my comment under the answer of the other question?

Comment: @Brannon Re edit: The screenshot of the devtools suggests that your problem isn't related to JS/jQuery, but caused by something at your server's end. In your PHP snippet, you've set a response header. However, this header is absent in your screenshot. Also, `Content-Length: 0` indicates that the server's response is really **empty**.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you have two `type` fields in your AJAX request? `jsonp` and `POST`.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",  // OK
    url: "http://localhost:8888/quartzsite/uploadendpoint.php",
    type: "jsonp", // ???
    // ...
});
```

**UPDATE:**

I think you should be using the relative path for the URL. Try changing your request to the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/quartzsite/uploadendpoint.php",
    dataType: "text/html",
    data: {img: encode64String},
    success: function(data){
        console.log("The ajax request succeeded!");
        console.log("The result is: ");
        console.dir(data);
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log("The request failed");
    }
});
```

You can see I replaced the URL with `/quartzsite/uploadendpoint.php`. This may solve the problem... the absolute URL might signal a cross-domain request which is not what you're after.

Also, as a side note, it's unnecessary to set the contentType, since what you're setting it to is already the default value. If you were sending a JSON or XML, then you'd want to set the contentType.

Comment: Nice catch! I have removed the "jsonp" type and added the correct `dataType`. The request is now failing altogether (which might actually indicate that it was previously giving a false positive).

Comment: You shouldn't be using "jsonp" anywhere in your request. That is an advanced method for cross-domain requests and I doubt it's what you need. Do you still have that in there?

Answer (score 0):

Use "echo" instead of "return" while sending the response data to ajax.

Comment: ... care to elaborate? Echo isn't a javascript function that I've heard of... I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @leinaD_natipaC I am saying in the controller. Not in JS.

Comment: This happened to be the problem in my case.